Fundamental group of the complement of a codimension two submanifold
Let $M$ denote an arbitrary smooth, closed, connected, n-dimensional manifold for $n\geq 4$. For every such $M$, does there exist a closed (not necessarily connected!) codimension two submanifold $S \subset M$ such that $\pi_1(M\setminus S)$ is a free group? If not, what if one replaces $M$ by $M\# N$ for some other $n$-manifold $N$?
A couple of thoughts on this:

By playing around with a nice triangulation of $M$ one can easily construct a codimension two subcomplex of $M$ such that its complement has free fundamental group. But of course resolving the singularities seems complicated, this is why the connected sum might be helpful.

If $n$ is big enough, I think, that the number of connected components of $S$ bounds the number of relations in $\pi_1(M)$. Because then the complement can be arranged to have a handle decompositon without two-handles and then the only two-handles of $M$ come from the $n-2$ handles in $S$.

If $S$ has simply-connected components, then the canonical map $M \to B\pi_1(M)$ factorizes through a complex of geometric dimension two, which is impossible for many $M$.

I think if $M$ has dimension three, then this is impossible since there are too few manifolds with free fundamental group.

Finally if $M$ is simply-connected, then this is easy.



As you suspect, in dimension 3 the answer to your first question should be "no". Indeed, if one deletes any collection of circles from $M$ then the complement is a 3-manifold with toroidal boundary. Since the fundamental group is free, no boundary component can $\pi_1$-embed. But then, by Dehn's lemma, every boundary component is compressible. There's something to check here, but I think it follows that the complement is a connect sum of solid tori and $S^1\times S^2$'s, whence $M$ has to be a connect sum of lens spaces and $S^1\times S^2$'s.

Yes I was expecting a similar argument, since 3-manifolds with free fundamental group are so restricted, so that one has to end up with something that can be build from $S^1 \times S^2$.

Now that I understand your question I see it's very close to the question of asking which manifolds have handle decompositions such that the 2-skeleton is homotopy-equivalent to a wedge of 2-spheres.  The main difference is you are concerned with fundamental groups rather than homotopy-type.

Are you assuming existence of a handle decomposition (which is true in dimensions $\ne 4$)?

@MoisheKohan Oh, I see. I never specified the manifolds to be smooth since I didn't see it as necessary. So feel free to assume that they are smooth or have a handlebody decomposition!

@HJRW do you want to post your comment as an a sweetheart? I would prefer to grab you the bounty than Ryan.

@ThorbenK: done! Thanks for the suggestion.

To your first question, the answer is yes.
Take a $k$-component trivial link in $S^n$, i.e. the boring, linear embedding
$$\sqcup_k S^{n-2} \to S^n$$
that is the boundary of a linear embedding
$$\sqcup_k D^{n-1} \to S^n.$$
The fundamental group of the exterior of this link is the free group on $k$ elements provided $n \geq 3$.
As a manifold the exterior (of an open tubular neighbourhood of this embedding) is diffeomorphic to a connect-sum of $k$ copies of $S^1 \times D^{n-1}$.
Perhaps I'm misreading your question but I don't see how you have ruled out this basic example.

I think you misread the question and a (manifold) means arbitrary rather than some.

The manifold $M$ is fixed.

Yes exactly! I'm interested in whether this is possible for an arbitrary $M$. For the application  I have in mind though it would suffice of $M$ has non-zero simplicial volume.

@ThorbenK: the way your question was asked threw me off, as you describe in some detail why the answer is no for arbirary $M$.   So it looked like you were searching for a case where the answer is yes, as the other interpretation has been ruled-out.

@RyanBudney I changed the wording a bit, maybe it's less ambiguous now.

As you suspect, in dimension 3 the answer to your first question should be "no". Indeed, if one deletes any collection of circles from $M$ then the complement is a 3-manifold with toroidal boundary. Since the fundamental group is free, no boundary component can $\pi_1$ embed. But then, by Dehn's lemma, every boundary component is compressible. It follows that the complement is a connect sum of solid tori and $S^1\times S^2$’s, whence $M$ has to be a connect sum of lens spaces and $S^1\times S^2$’s.
